# Cannot access elements of the container

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I have a QML object as follows:

```
// File: ControlView.qml
Rectangle {
    id: view
    property bool darkBackground: false

    Text {
        id: textSingleton
    }

    SoundEffect {
        id: playCalSound
        source: "qrc:/sound/calender_time_camera.wav"
    }
}
```

I have another control that is contained within it and my issue is that I cannot access the `playCalSound` or `textSingleton` elements.

```
// File: MyControl.qml
ControlView {
   ....
   playCalSound.play() // playCalSound is not defined
   textSingleton.font.pixelSize // textSingleton is not defined

   view.textSingleton // view is not defined
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define properties for objects you want use outside file. Try this

```
Rectangle {
    id: view
    property bool darkBackground: false
    property var effect: playCalSound
    property alias singletext: textSingletone.text

    Text {
        id: textSingleton
    }

    SoundEffect {
        id: playCalSound
        source: "qrc:/sound/calender_time_camera.wav"
    }
}

..............


ControlView {
   ....
   Component.onComplited: effect.play()

   singletext: 'some text'
}
```